# executing a curl request with a shell command in java?

Tags: java, shell, curl

I am wondering how to run this command line code for an API that I have found on the web. The code the API wants me to run goes as follows:

`curl -i "https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v1/prices?instruments=EUR_USD"`

This code will give data back in a JSON response. I am trying to accomplish this by running this threw a shell command. My code goes as follows:

```
import java.io.*;

public class FxTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FxTest obj = new FxTest();


        String command = "curl -i \"https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v1/prices?instruments=EUR_USD\"";


        String output = obj.executeCommand(command);

        System.out.println(output);

    }

    private String executeCommand(String command) {

        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader = 
                            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                        String line = "";           
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output.toString();

    }

}
```

When I run this code I get this error:

`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "curl": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

Will a shell command execute this code that I am trying to execute or is their a better way to go about this? If this code is impossible to execute in a shell command what options do I have, how do these options work and Where should I look to learn more. If a shell command is a good way to go about this than what is wrong with my code and where should I look to learn more about how to use a shell command? Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: I'd recommend some native methods (Request class). If you still want to do it with an exec, you should pass the command as a `String []` with the first element being the shell.

`String [] cmd = { {"/bin/bash/"}, {"curl"}, {"-i"}, {"'https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v1/prices?instruments=EUR_USD\'"}};`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the native java methods for this: HttpURLConnection? It is a little long winded as you can see in this tutorial: http://www.journaldev.com/7148/java-httpurlconnection-example-to-send-http-getpost-requests. Better still, try the apache httpclient. It has a nice fluid interface that lets you call a url as simple as:

```
// Execute a GET with timeout settings and return response content as String.
 Request.Get("http://somehost/") .execute().returnContent().asString();
```

Then you can use one of the java Jason  libraries to manipulate the results. json-simple is among the easiest to use (but there are lots to choose from): https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple. You start by parsing the string returned by the http call above:

```
Object obj=JSONValue.parse(s);
```